# reading and playing a word in the message window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with the code and an error message appears in word -> word = "" word = str (Entry.get (input_text)) which obviously refers to printing full text which does not work the way I want it when I want it to work in a non-root window window but reading window.

This is the codes :

```py
from tkinter import *
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

#---------
root = Tk()
root.title("Window")
#----------

#toiminnot root ikkunassa

functions = Label(root, text = "Select an action!")
functions.place(x = 70, y= 10)

#lue toimonto koodi alkaa

def read():
    reading_window = Tk()
    reading_window.title("Read function")
    frame = Frame(reading_window)
    frame.pack()

    read_the_text = Label(reading_window, text = "Enter text in the box!")
    read_the_text.place(x = 70, y = 10)

    word = ""
    word = str(Entry.get(input_text))

#frame johon kirjoitetaan

    input_text = Entry(reading_window)
    input_text.place(x=55, y=30)

#lueikkuna koko ja sijoitus

    reading_window.geometry("300x300+100+100")

#lue sana painike joka tuo viestin

    print_button = tk.Button(reading_window, text = 'Show typed text', height = 1, width = 15) #, command = print1)
    print_button.place(x=80, y=60)

    text_a_tip = Label(reading_window, text ="The typed text is displayed in\nthe message window!")
    text_a_tip.place(x = 50, y = 90)

def print1():
    tk.messagebox.showinfo('Kirjoitetun tekstin tulostus viestiikkunaan', (Entry.get(input_text)))

    def close():
        reading_window.destroy() 

    read_close_button = tk.Button(reading_window, text = 'Close the reading function', height = 1, width = 20, command = close)
    read_close_button.place(x = 60, y = 270)

    read.mainloop()

#lue toiminto koodi loppuu

read_function = tk.Button(root, text='Read function', height = 1, width = 15, command = read)
read_function.place(x = 55,y = 35)

#ohjleman lopettamisen koodi alkaa

def quit_prog():
    MsgBox = tk.messagebox.askquestion('Quit program', ' Are you sure you want to close the program?',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox == 'yes':
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit(0)

    else:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Back','Now you are back!')

quit_programbutton = tk.Button(root, text='Close program', height = 1, width = 15, command = quit_prog)
quit_programbutton.place(x=50, y=220)

#ohjelman lopettamisen koodi loppuu tÃ¤hÃ¤n
#----------
#----------
root.geometry("250x250+20+60") #"450x450=leveysxkorkeus"+"20+40=vasenreuna+ylÃ¤reuna"
root.mainloop()
```

[source](http://www.elisanet.fi/janikotisivu/koodit/syoteikkuna_joka_valitaan_root-ikkunasta.py)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what is "word" variable for, but I assume that You need it. You can't use variable defined under line in which you use it.

```
    word = ""
    word = str(Entry.get(input_text))   # input_text is defined below, interpreter doesn't know what is it  "input_text" yet.

    input_text = Entry(reading_window)
    input_text.place(x=55, y=30)
```

It should be rather.

```
    input_text = Entry(reading_window)
    input_text.place(x=55, y=30)
    word = ""
    word = str(Entry.get(input_text))   # now there is no error
```

It doesn't solve your problem, because I see that in function print1 you use again imput_text but it's defined in different function so it won't work.

```
def print1():
    # input_text is local variable in read function.
    tk.messagebox.showinfo('Kirjoitetun tekstin tulostus viestiikkunaan', (Entry.get(input_text)))
```

To solve your problem you can pass input_text as argument of print1, like in this working example.

```
def read():
    reading_window = Tk()
    reading_window.title("Read function")
    frame = Frame(reading_window)
    frame.pack()

    read_the_text = Label(reading_window, text = "Enter text in the box!")
    read_the_text.place(x = 70, y = 10)

    input_text = Entry(reading_window)
    input_text.place(x=55, y=30)
    word = ""
    word = str(Entry.get(input_text))
    reading_window.geometry("300x300+100+100")
    # pass input_text to print1
    print_button = tk.Button(reading_window, text = 'Show typed text', height = 1, width = 15, command = lambda: print1(input_text))
    print_button.place(x=80, y=60)

    text_a_tip = Label(reading_window, text ="The typed text is displayed in\nthe message window!")
    text_a_tip.place(x = 50, y = 90)

def print1(input_text):
    # print1 takes now one argument and has reference to input_text
    tk.messagebox.showinfo('Kirjoitetun tekstin tulostus viestiikkunaan', (Entry.get(input_text)))

    def close():
        reading_window.destroy() 

    read_close_button = tk.Button(reading_window, text = 'Close the reading function', height = 1, width = 20, command = close)
    read_close_button.place(x = 60, y = 270)

    read.mainloop()
```

Consider also using different geometry manager than place, it is even written in effbot doc:

> It is usually not a good idea to use place for ordinary window and dialog layouts; its simply to much work to get things working as they should. Use the pack or grid managers for such purposes.

[Place Geometry Manager](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)